# Query to get data from two tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to get data from two MySQL tables, but having problems.

Usually, I'd use join to get data from two those tables depending on data, but this time I cannot, I think.

Here's situation:
I'm having tables photos and photos_albums.

```
photos ID ALBUM FILENAME
photos_albums ID TITLE NAME
```

I need to get all albums and photo if exist in photos table. When I use join query will return albums only if photo with specific album id exists.

How to resolve? Any suggestions? Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Can you post the query and structure of `photos_albums`? My crystal ball is broken at the moment ;)

Comment: Mine too :) photos_albums does not matter, but edited my question :)

Comment: What does photos_album contain. Also what do you want if there is more than one photo in an album?

Comment: I want to display every album no matter if photo exists or not. If photo exists I'd like to get only one, no need for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probalby you are using `INNER JOIN` (or just `JOIN`, which is the same), this way you are given the rows that have data in both tables. Try so `select from albums` and `LEFT JOIN` with photos table.

Comment: No comments please. Of course LEFT JOIN works correctly, I'm just too tired. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

When joining two tables, you can specify the join type in order to return records that have matching criteria (in the `ON` clause), or all records from one of the join tables, regardless if it has a corresponding row in the other table. This can be achieved by using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.